# counting sort algorithm not working in hackerrank

Tags: c++, sorting, for-loop, max, stdvector

*this is my code*

```
vector<int> countingSort(vector<int> arr) {
    int max = arr[0];
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[0]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    max++;
    vector<int> frequency_arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        frequency_arr.push_back(0);
    }
    
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        int elem = arr[i];
        frequency_arr[elem]++;
    }
    
    return frequency_arr;
}
```

**explanation** : "countingSort" function is a sorting function which sort elements by using "counting sort" algorithm. it takes vector array as an input and return the "frequency array" as output.

**input array**
63 25 73 1 98 73 56 84 86 57 16 83 8 25 81 56 9 53 98 67 99 12 83 89 80 91 39 86 76 85 74 39 25 90 59 10 94 32 44 3 89 30 27 79 46 96 27 32 18 21 92 69 81 40 40 34 68 78 24 87 42 69 23 41 78 22 6 90 99 89 50 30 20 1 43 3 70 95 33 46 44 9 69 48 33 60 65 16 82 67 61 32 21 79 75 75 13 87 70 33

**my output**
0 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 3 0 2 0 0 2 0 3 3 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 2 1 3 2

**expected output**
**0 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 3 0 2 0 0 2 0 3 3 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 2 1 3 2** 0 0 2 1 2 1 0 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 0 3 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 2 2

**Constraints**
length of input array -> [100, 10^6]
range of elements in array -> [1, 100]

i was solving a counting sort problem in **hackerrank**, but when i run the code , in output it do not show all element of "**frequency_arr**"

it only show the bold numbers in expected output and do not show the remaning elements.

do you know what i am doing wrong here and what are the potential fixes?

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko He's doing `max++;` before pushing so it's fine. He could just do `std::vector<int> frequency_arr(max + 1);` instead of both `max++;` and `push_back`s though

Comment: Note: This implementation is potentially very dangerous. Since the array holds `int` values, one should expect negative values (unless they are guaranteed to not exist in the array).

Comment: @TedLyngmo worse they compare int iterator to size_t. And on top of that int can be 16bit so it doesn't meat the spec

Comment: *do you know what i am doing wrong here and what are the potential fixes?* -- To add what was already stated, debugging *your own code* is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  It isn't enough to write code, see it doesn't work, then go to StackOverflow, and sit back while others are debugging the code that *you wrote*.  Please learn to find these mistakes yourself -- you are not required to know *how* to fix the problem, since the fix could be complex, but at the very least, you're required to identify *where* the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a typo in the first for loop

```
int max = arr[0];
for(unsigned int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if(arr[i] > arr[0]) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

You need to write the if statement within the for loop the following way

```
    if(arr[i] > max) {
```

Moreover in general the variable `i` should have the type `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`.

```
for( size_t i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
```

Pay attention to that there is standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in header `<algorithm>`.

And instead of this code snippet

```
vector<int> frequency_arr;
for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    frequency_arr.push_back(0);
}
```

you could just write

```
vector<int> frequency_arr( max );
```

In this case all `max` elements of the vector will be zero-initialized.